# Automatically add braces to switch case statements using Eclipse quick fix

Tags: java, eclipse, autocomplete, switch-statement

When using Eclipse's Quick Assist in Java for adding missing case statements to a switch statement, I want to add braces to each auto-generated case statement automatically, but am unable.  This has proven an ongoing waste of time and led to much frustration.

I have tried updating multiple eclipse preferences to no avail, the most likely of which is Java) Code Style) Formatter profile, which allows you to specify the various spacing and formatting options around the braces, but not whether to include them.  It may be that this is possible using Code Snippets, but I can't figure out the mechanism to add my own and format it.  Likewise, it may be possible to accomplish the same thing using the Editor Templates, which will at least allow me to create a 'correctly' formatted switch statement, but I can't figure out how to make it auto-generate the enumerated values for the different cases.

So:

```java
switch (currentNode.getProjectType()) {

}
```

becomes:

```java
switch (currentNode.getProjectType()) {
    case PROJECT:
        break;
    ...

    default:
        break;          
}
```

instead of:

```java
switch (currentNode.getProjectType()) {
    case PROJECT: {
        break;
    }
    ...

    default: {
        break;
    }           
}
```

Comment: You don't need the `{}` for the cases in a `switch`.

Comment: While it is true that the {} are not strictly needed, I often work with language parsing/representation where type inheritance (and thus switch statements) can be nested multiple times.  A simplistic example would be TargetLanguageObject -> CapabilityObject -> RequirementObject-> LogicalRequirment.  See the comment below:

Comment: Imagine:

switch (targetLanguageObject.getTargetedLanguagueObjectType()) {
  case CapabilityObject {
    CapabilityObject capabilityObject = (CapabilityObject) targetedLanguageObject);
    switch (capabilityObject.getCapabilityObjectType()) {
      case Requirement: {
         Requirement requirement = (Requirement) capabilityObject;
         switch (requirement.getRequirementType()) {
           case LogicalRequirement: {
             // finally doing something with the object
             break;
           }
       ...         
}
````
without any braces to understand.